# Error Generando Codigo QR Aleatorio con Async Await

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async-await, qrcode

Saludos.

Estoy intentando generar codigos QR con nodejs de forma aleatoria pero siempre obtengo como resultado el mismo codigo qr base64.

```
aChtwo5eF7                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
vHXhJoldQJ                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
qKTwoy7gxd                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
KGlNhLIMTF                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
bmCiNnDwvp                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
olh67ej1xV                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
pUA0VghGpr                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
q0aRptpb0b                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7 
vI4sQ9uNi2                                                                                        
Task One:  data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAACgAKAAACD4yPqcvtAGGKElV1JzCgAAA7
```

Como se muestra en la imagen, el primer dato es un codigo aleatorio de 10 digitos y el segundo se trata de un codigo QR Base64 para generar una imagen basado en la informacion proporcionada.

Quisiera de su colaboracion para que me orienten cual puede ser el problema que estoy presanto...

A continuacion les indico el codigo utilizado.

index.js

```
const {taskOne, taskTwo }   =   require('./task.js');

async function main()
{
    try {
        for (let index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
            const   valueOne    =   await taskOne(index);            
            console.log("Task One: ", valueOne);
            delete valueOne;
        }        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

main();
```

Task.js

```
const util      =   require('util');
const sleep     =   util.promisify(setTimeout);
const base64    =   require('yaqrcode');
const QRCode    =   require('qrcode');

module.exports  =   {
    async taskOne(x)
    {
        try {
            // throw new Error('some problem');
            await sleep(1000);
            const random    =  await generateRandomString(10);
            console.log(random);           
            const qr    =  await qrCodeFun(random);
            return qr;
            
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
}

async function qrCodeFun(x)
{
    return base64(x, { size: 10});
}

async function generateRandomString(myLength) {
    const chars =
      "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1234567890";
    const randomArray = Array.from(
      { length: myLength },
      (v, k) => chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)]
    );
  
    const randomString = randomArray.join("");
    return randomString;
  };
```

Gracias de antemano por su colaboracion.

Comment: Posiblemente sea un problema de cache. Donde mandas a llar la imagen? Puedes intertar poner algo así: `src="img/qr?parametro_cualquiera=numero_aleatorio"`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta... Pero el inconveniente viene en el async await del QRCode... Que al momento de que el for haga su ciclo y espere la respuesta de la función envía es la que está en caché... Y siempre envía el mismo código...